# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel Grey Bars

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the  Twitter Bootstrap Carousel
is there any way not display the vertical grey bars at both the sides of the carousel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with **CSS**

```css
.carousel-control.left, 
.carousel-control.right {
    background-image: none
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/L5C9Y/)

### How to do it yourself:

1. Go to a site that has the `bootstrap carousel`.  I went to the [documentation page](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)
2. In Chrome (or whatever browser you like) use `Inspect Element` to see a list of all the matched CSS rules.  **Something** is giving it that styling, and it's going to have to live here.
3. Find one that looks like the culrprit and uncheck the box to see if removing that style makes a difference

   - [image: demo]

**Note**: You shouldn't change bootstrap.css, but you can override it by placing your changed css later.  If it doesn't work, try `!important`

Best of luck!

Comment: Good to show how it should be done to find it yourself. Normally `!important` isn't advised, but here you have to indeed.

Answer (score 0):

you can change  "boostrap.css" file..(2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css)
you can find and "#999" (color code)  replace anything you want or delete.

Comment: I am using the css downloaded from netdna. May I override it? how should I do that?

Comment: @BarisKurt, you should **not** change the core files provided by any third party project.  They **will** update their libraries, and when they do, you'll have a hard time if you've modified them inline.  Just override anything you want to in a css file that is parsed after theirs.